# ExceptionHandler does not handle exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, jax-rs

I'm making a RestApi in Spring boot. I tried to add exception handling so the client gets meaningful response other than 404.

This is my RestController:

```
@Path("/v1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserRestService {

  
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{publicId}")
    public RestResponse<UserListItemRestDto> getUserByPublicId(@PathParam("publicId") UUID publicId) {

        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findOneByPublicId(publicId);

        if(optionalUser.isEmpty()){
            throw new ApiRequestException("CANNOT FIND USER");
        }

        User user = optionalUser.get();

        return RestResponse.of(UserListItemRestDto.builder()
                        .email(user.getEmail())
                        .name(user.getName())
                .build());
    }

...
```

My ExceptionHandler:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ApiRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiException> handleApiRequestException(ApiRequestException e){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiException(e.getMessage(),
          e.getCause(),
          HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, 
          ZonedDateTime.now()),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

My CustomException:

```
public class ApiRequestException extends RuntimeException{

    public ApiRequestException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

    public ApiRequestException(String message, Throwable cause){
        super(message,cause);
    }
}
```

Currently if no user found it throws the exception but doesn't get handled.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: com.common.rest.exception.ApiRequestException: CANNOT FIND USER
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.common.rest.exception.ApiRequestException: CANNOT FIND USER
    at com.backend.flows.user.rest.UserRestService.getUserByPublicId(UserRestService.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492) ~[resteasy-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Is the Handler not scanned or I left out an annotation or a misconfig?

Comment: Any reason why your RestController is a `@Service` and not `@RestController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using JAX-RS (RESTEasy) rather than spring-mvc to implement the REST API while `@RestControllerAdvice` is the spring-mvc stuff and so it is normal that JAX-RS cannot understand it and does not have any effect.

You should refer to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.5.Final/userguide/html/ch30.html) for how to handle exception in JAX-RS way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. You may need to use `@RestController` to annotate your controller

```java
@RestController
public class UserRestService {
//....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this did the trick:

```
@Provider
@Component
public class ApiExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException ex) {
        
       
        int defaultHttpErrorCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value();
        return Response.status(defaultHttpErrorCode).entity(new EmptyRestResponse()).build();
    }
}
```

For your information: Provider and Component annotaions are needed.